# IronPython 2.7/ 2.6 for .Net4 Install Error

Tags: .net-4.0, installation, ironpython, windows-7-x64

I am gettting some really annoying errors while attempting to install IronPython so I can work with .Net4 assemblies.

I have tried both the .Net4 compatible installer versions of IronPython and both give me an error. The 2.7 one says it has had a problem installing assembly  error code 2908. The 2.6 for .Net4 installer just says it has encountered an error and rolls back.

I have IronPython2.6 installed and working fine. But I need the .Net4 upgrade, I am running Win7 x64. Think maybe the OS configuration might be at fault? I realise this isn't a straight programming question, but I was hoping some of the SO community might be able to shed some light on this one, where my Google bashing has not.

Comment: A good place to start would be to run `msiexec /i IronPython-2.7.msi /l*v .\install.log` from the command prompt, which will create the verbose MSI log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't *need* it to be installed, you can use the [.zip package](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/54498#DownloadId=216705) to get the files. The only thing the installer really does is add the assemblies to the GAC.

Comment: Good point Jeff. I tried this method as a potential before I dived into MSI logs. The new interpreter worked. So I'm happy. I'll save the in depth analysis for another time when I don't need to use it as urgently. I still think it may have something to do with the Win7 declaring all .Net's previous to 4 as OS compenents. Which seems to create all sorts of compatibility problems... anyway. Thanks for all your help!